# I want to know the effect of assigning vSRX to Public VLAN

Tags: ibm-cloud

There is a WebServer open to the Internet.
This WebServer belongs to Public VLAN 11x1.
If I introduce vSRX later and make it belong to Public VLAN11x1, will communication be blocked by vSRX?
If all communication is via vSRX at the timing of joining vSRX to Public VLAN11x1,
I am worried that I might block if I don't have an ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps at the "Manage VLAN" link below to associate ("route around") your public VLAN with the vSRX. Then login and configure your vSRX with the desired zones/rules (see doc examples below). Finally, follow the "Manage VLAN" doc to "route through" the public VLAN so the routers know to route the traffic on your VLAN to the vSRX.

Manage VLANs: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/vsrx?topic=gateway-appliance-managing-vlans-and-gateway-appliances

vSRX Firewall Configuration Example: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/vsrx?topic=vsrx-working-with-firewalls

Juniper Public to Private NAT Example:
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos12.1x46/topics/example/nat-security-destination-single-address-translation-configuring.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But sorry,I can't open the [Manage VLANs: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/vsrx?topic=gateway-appliance-managing-vlans-and-gateway-appliances].

Could you give me the other link?

Comment: The link should be publicly accessible: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/vsrx?topic=gateway-appliance-managing-vlans-and-gateway-appliances

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I can't open the link yet.
But,I found similar link.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/infrastructure/gateway-appliance?topic=gateway-appliance-managing-vlans-and-gateway-appliances

Is this link the same as the link you introduced?

Comment: Yes, that is the link.